# Replacing Jenkins' Extended Choice or Active Choice Delimiter for Checkbox

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, command, jenkins-plugins

How do I retrieve the value of checkboxes from Active Choice or Extended Choice Plugin in a way that it will not show the values with comma separated? I am asking this because I could not execute my batch command if the class files are separated by comma.

Checboxes:

- Test1
- Test2

Batch Command:

`java -cp . Test1,Test2`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by updating the delimiter field on Extended Choice Parameter, just happens that it overrides the separator.